Why vacuum analyze takes much time in an empty table?
I have a table in my database that used to have data long time ago, but now data have been deleted and is empty and no new data are inserted on it.
Once a day I run vacuum analyze for several tables and for this specific one I noticed that it takes much time. Below is the verbose output
2024-10-03 07:12:22,217 INFO Vacuum/Analyze output: [INFO:  vacuuming 
"public.activity_by_cgi_rat"
INFO:  index "activity_sec_by_cgi_rat_pk" now contains 0 row versions in 10940559 
pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
10940553 index pages have been deleted, 10940553 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 18.87 s, system: 52.19 s, elapsed: 2627.28 s.
INFO:  "activity_by_cgi_rat": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out 
of 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 1176039973
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 18.87 s, system: 52.19 s, elapsed: 2627.28 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_21943"
INFO:  index "pg_toast_21943_index" now contains 0 row versions in 1 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.03 s.
INFO:  "pg_toast_21943": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 
pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 1176065166
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.06 s.
INFO:  analyzing "public.activity_by_cgi_rat"
INFO:  "activity_by_cgi_rat": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead 
rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
]
2024-10-03 07:12:22,218 INFO msgtype=PERF component=analytics.rdb 
operation=db_expire.vacuum_db_table elapsed_sec=2627.60 db_table=activity_by_cgi_rat

Almost 1h for an empty is much time isn't it? Why is this happening?
I notice this line in the verbose output:
INFO:  index "activity_sec_by_cgi_rat_pk" now contains 0 row 
versions in 10940559 pages

which looks suspicious: Why in an empty table so much pages?
--- EDIT ---
I read in docs the following:
In PostgreSQL 7.4 and later, index pages that have become completely empty are reclaimed for re-use. There is still a possibility for inefficient use of space: if all but a few index keys on a page have been deleted, the page remains allocated. So a usage pattern in which all but a few keys in each range are eventually deleted will see poor use of space. For such usage patterns, periodic reindexing is recommended.

Is it possible that I have to reindex the table?
